# Why is Google drive listing V3 API only showing subset of documents

Tags: google-drive-api

Expectation: I need all the Google documents that are publicly available on my company domain.

Problem: Audit report shows there are 17K documents that are available to all employees being on the same domain(xyz.com) but API lists only 6k documents.

API Used : **https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/reference/files/list**

Options Set: **“includeItemsFromAllDrives”**  and **“includeTeamDriveItems”** to “true”.
nextPageToken is used correctly and I see only 6k documents that is getting listed out of 17K.

Am I missing any parameter to be sent for the API. Also, what is the configuration necessary on the Google Drive admin side to get this working?

Comment: Does this still happen even if you query the API with these parameters: `{
      "corpora": "allDrives",
      "includeItemsFromAllDrives": true,
      "includeTeamDriveItems": true,
      "supportsAllDrives": true,
      "supportsTeamDrives": true
    }`?

Comment: does the audit report count files in Trash?

Comment: @ZektorH : Thanks for the suggestion. I did try with the options that you mentioned.I am seeing only 2.7k documents.

Comment: @pinoyyid : Audit report contains only valid files and not from trash.

 The strange behavior with this is  - when I do a search on the google drive (https://drive.google.com/drive/u/2/my-drive) 
I see all those documents (which are not pulled from the API) as a recommendation in the search dropdown as I type the title of the documents but when I hit enter they never show up in the results section below.

Comment: I noticed from your previous comment that your Google drive link has `/u/2`, meaning you are using your third logged-in user to browse the files. Are you sure you are executing the API call on the right account?

Comment: @ZektorH - When I try to hit the API via [https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/reference/files/list] it asks for a authentication and I am selecting the appropriate user account to make the API call.

I see better results when I pass 'domain' as the corpora field value to the API.
Do you foresee any issues passing 'domain' with corpora field.

Comment: Are you getting a `incompleteSearch` flag as detailed [here](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v2/search-files#search_the_corpora)?

Comment: @ZektorH Yes. I think things are looking good. 

Thanks for all the help. Will update this thread if I see any issues in this approach.

Answer (score 0):

The solution to this problem was to verify the `incompleteSearch` flag that is detailed [here](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/search-files#search_the_corpora).